# Return empty action or observable in effect (angular redux/ngrx)

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, angular7

I'm uploading a file to server and I would like to track upload progress without spamming with many actions (on each http event). Is it possible to return something like null or empty observable in some cases? Because I want to dispatch an action only in two cases - success or failure. And now I must return an action in each http event type and it's becoming a spam then..

```
@Effect()
public createMediaItem: Observable<Action> = this._actions
    .pipe(
        ofType(MediaItemActionTypes.MediaItemCreateAction),
        map((action: MediaItemCreateAction) => action),
        switchMap(action => {
            return this._uploadService.createMediaItem(action.formData)
                .pipe(
                    map((event: HttpEvent<HttpEventType>) => {
                        switch (event.type) {
                            case HttpEventType.UploadProgress: {
                                console.log('ignore');
                                action.fileItem.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                                break;
                                // return;
                            }

                            case HttpEventType.Response: {
                                return new MediaItemCreateSuccessAction();
                            }
                            default:
                                break;
                            // return;
                        }
                    })
                );
        })
    );
```

Comment: You can't track an upload progress without HTTP events. for the first & last events, I would suggest handling it in the HTTP call directly, with `tap` and `finalize`, which would trigger at request creation and at request ending.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Rx.Observable.empty:**

To return an empty action, you can use the [empty](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-empty) observable from **RxJS**.

**empty(scheduler: Scheduler): Observable**

Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits a complete notification.

```
var result = Rx.Observable.empty();
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Thank you! I would've probably used this solution, but I found another workaround in the meantime. I will post it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution is below. I decided not to dispatch an action straightly from effect, for that matter I use store to dispatch the action only when I need.

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
public createMediaItem: Observable<void> = this._actions
    .pipe(
        ofType(MediaItemActionTypes.MediaItemCreateAction),
        map((action: MediaItemCreateAction) => action),
        mergeMap(action => {
            return this._uploadService.createMediaItem(action.formData)
                .pipe(
                    map((event: HttpEvent<HttpEventType>) => {
                        switch (event.type) {
                            case HttpEventType.UploadProgress: {
                                action.fileItem.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                                break;
                            }

                            case HttpEventType.Response: {
                                this._store.dispatch(new MediaItemCreateSuccessAction(action.fileItem, event.body));
                                break;
                            }

                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }),
                    catchError(error => of(this._store.dispatch(new MediaItemCreateFailAction(action.fileItem, error))))
                );
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that i found is returning an NeverObservable().

Rxjs 5.x.x
Usage:

```
import {NeverObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/NeverObservable';
return NeverObservable.create();
```

The NeverObservable will just stop the effect directly without expecting a return of Observable

Comment: return empty will not trigger the store.selects which are triggered by the effect?

Comment: No, this solution fits best for newest ngrx versions as well as { dispatch: false }. Depends on the specificity of effect.